# смена иконки в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Меняю стандартную иконку таким способом

```
root.iconbitmap('favicon.ico')
```

когда компилирую из `.py` в `.exe`  c помощью `pyinstaller` при запуске приложения выходит ошибка. Если закинуть иконку в папку с `.exe` тогда все хорошо.
обязательно ли хранить иконку в той же папке и можно ли сделать так чтобы иконку не хранить в той же папке?
указать полный пункт не подходит (`root.iconbitmap(r'c:\Desktop\favicon.ico')`)
т.к. при переносе `.exe` на другой компьютер его все равно не найдет по этому пути.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать опцию "--icon=icon.ico" при билде.

Comment: `pyinstaller -F -w -i C:\favicon.ico 1.py` компилю так ,куда это вписать?

Comment: судя по всему вместо "-i C:\favicon.ico", можно попробовать написать "--icon=favicon.ico". Иконку положите в папку, откуда будет вестись сборка.